# Trying To Set A String From A JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is what i am working for Look at StudentIDPrint for the JLabel that Prints them out and also StudentIDSS for the string with textfield is where the StudentIDSS is supposed to get its value from I really would love any tips and help thank you so much I think it could be where the code is placed but i really am lost here and any help would be lovely thank you all so much

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//Allows it too use JFrame
public class LiftingApp extends JFrame {

    //Calls them from import (like calling a Scanner)
    private JLabel EnterSID;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel WaukeeAPEX;
    private ImageIcon ThankIMG;
    private JLabel Thank;
    private JButton AdminButton;
    private JTextField AdminText;
    private JButton AdminButton2;
    private JLabel AdminThank;
    private JButton goback;
    private ImageIcon Login;
    private ImageIcon AdminLogin;
    private ImageIcon RTMS;
    private JLabel StudentIDPrint;

    public String StudentIDSS;

    public LiftingApp() 
    {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(LiftingApp.class.getResource("ICON.jpg")));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                goback = new JButton("Return To Main Screen");
                getContentPane().add(goback);

                goback.setVisible(false);

                event4 rb = new event4();
                goback.addActionListener(rb);

                AdminThank = new JLabel("Thank You For Loging in");
                AdminThank.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                getContentPane().add(AdminThank);

                AdminThank.setVisible(false);

                AdminButton2 = new JButton("Admin Login");
                getContentPane().add(AdminButton2);

                AdminButton2.setVisible(false);

                event3 al2 = new event3();
                AdminButton2.addActionListener(al2);

                AdminButton = new JButton("Admin Login");
                getContentPane().add(AdminButton);

                AdminText = new JTextField(10);
                getContentPane().add(AdminText);

                AdminText.setVisible(false);

                event2 al = new event2();
                AdminButton.addActionListener(al);

                //Adds a Button

                button = new JButton("Login");
                getContentPane().add(button);               

                //Adds Text
                EnterSID = new JLabel("Enter StudentID");
                EnterSID.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                getContentPane().add(EnterSID);

                event e = new event();
                button.addActionListener(e);

                //Adds Field (The box you type stuff in) 
                textfield = new JTextField(10);
                getContentPane().add(textfield);
                textfield.getText();

                //Adds Image
                image = new ImageIcon(getClass() .getResource("testt.png"));

                //Sets Image to the WaukeeAPEX JLabel
                WaukeeAPEX = new JLabel(image);
                getContentPane().add(WaukeeAPEX);

                ThankIMG = new ImageIcon(getClass() .getResource("testt2.png"));

                Thank = new JLabel(ThankIMG);
                getContentPane().add(Thank);

                Thank.setVisible(false);                

                StudentIDPrint = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(StudentIDPrint);
                StudentIDPrint.setVisible(false);
                StudentIDPrint.setText("Student IDS Are:" + StudentIDSS);       
    }               

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        //This is just talking about the window
        LiftingApp gui = new LiftingApp();
        //When you click the X it closes...
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Size of intial box (pack puts every thing you have to the smallest size to keep everything)
        gui.setSize(1000, 1000);
        //This makes it so you can see the Window
        gui.setVisible(true);
        //This Sets The Title
        gui.setTitle("Elmin Strength");


        //Dont Worry About any of this just learning Arrays

        //Array Initializer
    }

    //ActionListener Just waits for the action to happen then dose what is told
    public class event implements ActionListener {

        //Telling what the Action is
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            StudentIDSS = textfield.getText();

            //This will show after the button is pressed
            EnterSID.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(true);

            Thank.setVisible(true);

            AdminText.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(false);

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(false);

            goback.setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    public class event2 implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al){
            textfield.setVisible(false);


            EnterSID.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(true);

            AdminButton.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton2.setVisible(true);          

            goback.setVisible(true);

        }


    }

    public class event3 implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al2){

            String p = AdminText.getText();
            AdminButton2.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(true);
            AdminText.getSelectedText();

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

            if(p.compareTo("Password") == 0) {
            Thank.setVisible(true);
            goback.setVisible(true);
            AdminThank.setVisible(true);
            StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                goback.setVisible(true);
                AdminText.setVisible(false);

            }

        }
    }

    public class event4 implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rb) {

            goback.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(true);

            EnterSID.setVisible(true);

            textfield.setVisible(true);

            AdminButton.setVisible(true);

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(true);

            Thank.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton2.setVisible(false);

            AdminThank.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(false);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take some time and separate the logic into separate classes, so that you can use `CardLayout` to switch between the different possible views

Comment: *"I really would love any tips.."* Tip: ask a question.

Comment: From [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Spelling, grammar and ***punctuation*** are important" and "don't just copy in your entire program".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are playing with the LiftingApp..
I rearrange some of your code for convienient.

```
public LiftingApp() {   

    // skip... 

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    getContentPane().add(goback);
    getContentPane().add(AdminThank);
    getContentPane().add(AdminButton2);
    getContentPane().add(AdminButton);
    getContentPane().add(AdminText);
    getContentPane().add(button);
    getContentPane().add(EnterSID);
    getContentPane().add(textfield);
    getContentPane().add(WaukeeAPEX);
    getContentPane().add(Thank);
    getContentPane().add(StudentIDPrint);

    event4 rb = new event4();
    event3 al2 = new event3();
    event2 al = new event2();
    event e = new event();

    goback.addActionListener(rb);
    AdminButton2.addActionListener(al2);
    AdminButton.addActionListener(al);
    button.addActionListener(e);

    goback.setVisible(false);
    AdminThank.setVisible(false);
    AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
    AdminText.setVisible(false);
    Thank.setVisible(false);
    StudentIDPrint.setVisible(false);
}
```

Now, you have a FlowLayout as a layout of your class with 4 buttons and 4 action listeners.

It's enough you have only one listener for those actions.

I've just put those each listener's code to the one listener as a MainEvent class. There are several ways to use a action listener as you know. This might be one method.

```
class MainButtonEvt implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        System.out.println("====> ");

        if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) button)
        {
            System.out.println("====> login");

            StudentIDSS = textfield.getText();
            StudentIDPrint.setText("Student IDS Are:" + StudentIDSS);
            if(!StudentIDPrint.isVisible()) StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);

            // This will show after the button is pressed
            if(EnterSID.isVisible()) EnterSID.setVisible(false);
            if(!textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(true);
            if(!Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(true);
            if(AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(false);
            if(AdminButton.isVisible()) AdminButton.setVisible(false);
            if(button.isVisible()) button.setVisible(false);
            if(WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);
            if(AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(false);
            if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);

        }
        if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) goback)
        {
            System.out.println("====> goback");

            String p = textfield.getText();

            if(p != null && !p.equals(""))  textfield.setText("");

            if(goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(false);
            if(!button.isVisible()) button.setVisible(true);
            if(!EnterSID.isVisible()) EnterSID.setVisible(true);
            if(textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(false);
            if(!AdminButton.isVisible()) AdminButton.setVisible(true);
            if(!WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(true);
            if(Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(false);
            if(AdminButton2.isVisible()) AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
            if(AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(false);
            if(!AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(true);

        }
        if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) AdminButton)
        {
            System.out.println("====> AdminButton");


            if(AdminButton2.isVisible()) AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
            if(textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(false);
            if(!AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(true);

            String p = AdminText.getText();
            //p = AdminText.getSelectedText();

            if(WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

            if (p.compareTo("Password") == 0) {
                if(!Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(true);
                if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);
                if(!AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(true);
                if(!StudentIDPrint.isVisible()) 
                    StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);
                if(AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(false);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Then, you can call the main event class as follows;

```
MainButtonEvt mainEvt = new MainButtonEvt();

goback.addActionListener(mainEvt);
AdminButton2.addActionListener(mainEvt);
AdminButton.addActionListener(mainEvt);
button.addActionListener(mainEvt);
```

I hope you can find how to handle it.
Full source code:

```
package just.test.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

//Allows it too use JFrame
public class LiftingApp extends JFrame {

    // Calls them from import (like calling a Scanner)
    private JLabel EnterSID;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel WaukeeAPEX;
    private ImageIcon ThankIMG;
    private JLabel Thank;
    private JButton AdminButton;
    private JTextField AdminText;
    private JButton AdminButton2;
    private JLabel AdminThank;
    private JButton goback;
    private ImageIcon Login;
    private ImageIcon AdminLogin;
    private ImageIcon RTMS;
    private JLabel StudentIDPrint;

    public String StudentIDSS;

    public LiftingApp() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        File icon = new File("resource/images/hourglass.png");
        File icon2 = new File("resource/images/plus.png");
        File icon3 = new File("resource/images/minus.png");

        // setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(LiftingApp.class.getResource("ICON.jpg")));
        try {
            setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(icon.toURI().toURL()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        goback = new JButton("Return To Main Screen");
        AdminThank = new JLabel("Thank You For Loging in");
        AdminThank.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        AdminButton2 = new JButton("Admin Login2");
        AdminButton = new JButton("Admin Login");

        AdminText = new JTextField(10);

        // Adds a Button
        button = new JButton("Login");

        // Adds Text
        EnterSID = new JLabel("Enter StudentID");
        EnterSID.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        // Adds Field (The box you type stuff in)
        textfield = new JTextField(10);
        //textfield.getText();

        // Adds Image
        // image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("testt.png"));
        try {
            image = new ImageIcon(icon2.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Sets Image to the WaukeeAPEX JLabel
        WaukeeAPEX = new JLabel(image);

        // ThankIMG = new ImageIcon(getClass() .getResource("testt2.png"));
        try {
            ThankIMG = new ImageIcon(icon3.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thank = new JLabel(ThankIMG);

        StudentIDPrint = new JLabel();
        StudentIDSS = "";
        StudentIDPrint.setText("Student IDS Are:" + StudentIDSS);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        getContentPane().add(goback);
        getContentPane().add(AdminThank);
        getContentPane().add(AdminButton2);
        getContentPane().add(AdminButton);
        getContentPane().add(AdminText);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        getContentPane().add(EnterSID);
        getContentPane().add(textfield);
        getContentPane().add(WaukeeAPEX);
        getContentPane().add(Thank);
        getContentPane().add(StudentIDPrint);


        MainButtonEvt mainEvt = new MainButtonEvt();

        goback.addActionListener(mainEvt);
        AdminButton2.addActionListener(mainEvt);
        AdminButton.addActionListener(mainEvt);
        button.addActionListener(mainEvt);

        //event4 rb = new event4();
        //event3 al2 = new event3();
        //event2 al = new event2();
        //event e = new event();

        //goback.addActionListener(rb);
        //AdminButton2.addActionListener(al2);
        //AdminButton.addActionListener(al);
        //button.addActionListener(e);

        goback.setVisible(false);
        AdminThank.setVisible(false);
        AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
        AdminText.setVisible(false);
        Thank.setVisible(false);
        StudentIDPrint.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is just talking about the window
        LiftingApp gui = new LiftingApp();
        // When you click the X it closes...
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Size of intial box (pack puts every thing you have to the smallest
        // size to keep everything)
        gui.setSize(1200, 900);
        // This makes it so you can see the Window
        gui.setVisible(true);
        // This Sets The Title
        gui.setTitle("Elmin Strength");

        // Dont Worry About any of this just learning Arrays

        // Array Initializer
    }

    class MainButtonEvt implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("====> ");

            if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) button)
            {
                System.out.println("====> login");

                StudentIDSS = textfield.getText();
                StudentIDPrint.setText("Student IDS Are:" + StudentIDSS);
                if(!StudentIDPrint.isVisible()) StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);

                // This will show after the button is pressed
                if(EnterSID.isVisible()) EnterSID.setVisible(false);
                if(!textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(true);
                if(!Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(true);
                if(AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(false);
                if(AdminButton.isVisible()) AdminButton.setVisible(false);
                if(button.isVisible()) button.setVisible(false);
                if(WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);
                if(AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(false);
                if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);

            }
            if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) goback)
            {
                System.out.println("====> goback");

                String p = textfield.getText();

                if(p != null && !p.equals(""))  textfield.setText("");

                if(goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(false);
                if(!button.isVisible()) button.setVisible(true);
                if(!EnterSID.isVisible()) EnterSID.setVisible(true);
                if(textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(false);
                if(!AdminButton.isVisible()) AdminButton.setVisible(true);
                if(!WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(true);
                if(Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(false);
                if(AdminButton2.isVisible()) AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
                if(AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(false);
                if(!AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(true);

            }
            if(evt.getSource() == (JButton) AdminButton)
            {
                System.out.println("====> AdminButton");


                if(AdminButton2.isVisible()) AdminButton2.setVisible(false);
                if(textfield.isVisible()) textfield.setVisible(false);
                if(!AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(true);

                String p = AdminText.getText();
                //p = AdminText.getSelectedText();

                if(WaukeeAPEX.isVisible()) WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

                if (p.compareTo("Password") == 0) {
                    if(!Thank.isVisible()) Thank.setVisible(true);
                    if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);
                    if(!AdminThank.isVisible()) AdminThank.setVisible(true);
                    if(!StudentIDPrint.isVisible()) StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    if(!goback.isVisible()) goback.setVisible(true);
                    if(AdminText.isVisible()) AdminText.setVisible(false);

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // ActionListener Just waits for the action to happen then dose what is told
    public class event implements ActionListener {

        // Telling what the Action is
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            StudentIDSS = textfield.getText();

            // This will show after the button is pressed
            EnterSID.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(true);

            Thank.setVisible(true);

            AdminText.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(false);

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(false);

            goback.setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    public class event2 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al) {
            textfield.setVisible(false);

            EnterSID.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(true);

            AdminButton.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton2.setVisible(true);

            goback.setVisible(true);

        }

    }

    public class event3 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al2) {

            String p = AdminText.getText();
            AdminButton2.setVisible(false);

            textfield.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(true);
            AdminText.getSelectedText();

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(false);

            if (p.compareTo("Password") == 0) {
                Thank.setVisible(true);
                goback.setVisible(true);
                AdminThank.setVisible(true);
                StudentIDPrint.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                goback.setVisible(true);
                AdminText.setVisible(false);

            }

        }
    }

    public class event4 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rb) {

            goback.setVisible(false);

            button.setVisible(true);

            EnterSID.setVisible(true);

            textfield.setVisible(true);

            AdminButton.setVisible(true);

            WaukeeAPEX.setVisible(true);

            Thank.setVisible(false);

            AdminButton2.setVisible(false);

            AdminThank.setVisible(false);

            AdminText.setVisible(false);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this @tommybee but what i did was go from JTextField to a JLabel then take whats in the JLabel to a string :)

Answer (score 0):

First Sorry for posting my whole code in, Second What I did was make a JLabel that takes from the JTextField Then I made a String that takes from the JLabel

```js
StudentIDSSS = new JLabel(": " + textfield.getText() + ":");
   getContentPane().add(StudentIDSSS);
   StudentIDSSS.setVisible(true);
   
   String List = StudentIDSSS.getText();
   
   System.out.print(List);
   
   StudentIDList = new JLabel(List);
   getContentPane().add(StudentIDList);
   StudentIDList.setVisible(false);
```